# "Unknown custom element: <ShowList>" in browser with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I used vue cli create to setup a basic boilerplate project. I did some small modifications that initially worked. Then at some point both of my components stopped working in the browser. With no warnings from vue-cli-service serve.

In the browser console I get the error Unknown custom element for both of my elements.

Here is my main.js;

```
import './sass/style.scss'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/*
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
*/

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    render: h => h(App),
    components: { App }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Here is my App.vue;

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ShowList list_id="default"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShowList from './components/ShowList.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    ShowList
  }
}
</script>

<script lang="scss">
@import "sass/common.scss";

// Static footer
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: $footer_height; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
</script>
```

And here is one of the components;

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
                    <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                            <span class="text-muted">Din lista</span>
                    </h4>

                    <ul class="list-group mb-3">
        <li v-for="beer in beers" v-bind:key="beer.name" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">                                                                                 
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">{{ beer.name }}</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ beer.description }}</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">{{ beer.price }}</span>
        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
var beer_items = [
  {
    name: 'Hoegarden',
    price: '19:90 kr',
    description: 'Tyskt öl'
  },
  {
    name: 'Leffe',
    price: '16:90 kr',
    description: 'Belgiskt öl'
  },
  {
    name: 'Fat Tire',
    price: '17:50 kr',
    description: 'Amerikanskt öl'
  }
];

export default {
  name: 'ShowList',
  props: {
    list_id: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      beers: beer_items
    };
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.no-move {
  transition: transform 0s;
}
.ghost {
  opacity: .5;
  background: #C8EBFB;
}
.list-group {
  min-height: 20px;
}
.list-group-item {
  cursor: move;
}
.list-group-item i{
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

I tried using hyphenated component names like show-list too but it did not help.

I feel like I've missed something simple and essential but so far nobody on Vue Gitter has been able to figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could it be because you've got `<script lang="scss">` instead of `<style lang="scss">` tags in your App.vue?